# Telethon code, it's not performing the action on Telegram

Tags: python, telethon

I am new to the programming area and started with python this week. Through research, I wrote a code in Pycharm, it runs and doesn't show any errors but it's not executing the action on Telegram. Can someone help me? I don't have extensive knowledge, I've been working on this code for only 5 days with research, I hope someone can help me.

I would like the bot to forward each message from the main group to a specific group through keywords when a message arrives in the main group.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

# Use your own API ID and hash
api_id = 
api_hash = ''

# Create the client and start the session
client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

SUPER_GROUP_CHAT_ID = -1112223334

GROUP_CHAT_IDS = {'SIM': -112233445, 'NÃO': -544332211, 'EMPATE': -223355668, 'OVER 2,5': -445566332,
                  'OVER 3,5': -775588221}


async def forward_message(event: events.NewMessage.Event):
    message = event.message
    if message.to_id.channel_id == SUPER_GROUP_CHAT_ID:
        for keyword, channel_id in GROUP_CHAT_IDS.items():
            if keyword in message.message:
                print(f"Palavra-chave {keyword} encontrada, encaminhando para o canal {channel_id}")
                await client.forward_messages(channel_id, message)

client.add_event_handler(forward_message, events.NewMessage(incoming=True))

# Run the client
try:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('Exiting...')
    client.disconnect()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please enable `logging`, and use a debugger or add `print` statements to your code, to learn how far it is reaching and where it is getting stuck. As it is, we cannot provide much more help.

Comment: Thank you, it returned that the SSL library is missing, I am installing it at the moment.